# openshift deploy output has many: 'remote: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift) '

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, openshift

The deploy works fine, the output is just incredibly noisy:

```
% git push openshift
remote: Stopping Ruby cartridge        
remote: Stopping MySQL 5.5 cartridge        
remote: Saving away previously bundled RubyGems        
remote: Building git ref 'develop', commit 384b1c6        
remote: Building Ruby cartridge        
remote: Restoring previously bundled RubyGems        
remote: NOTE: You can commit .openshift/markers/force_clean_build to force a clean bundle        
remote: NOTE: Skipping 'bundle install' because Gemfile is not modified.        
remote: Preparing build for deployment        
remote: Deployment id is f3a42b22        
remote: Activating deployment        
remote: Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge        
remote: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift)        
remote: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).        
remote: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift)        
remote: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).        
remote: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift)        
remote: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).        
remote: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift)        
remote: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).        
remote: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift)        
remote: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).        
remote: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift)        
remote: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Each command openshift runs as part of the deploy generates 3-10 lines like this.

Any notion as to why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this error message. It was due to my `umask` setting the file mode of my `.git` directory incorrectly when I ran `git init`. Check the file modes of the `.git` and all subdirectories are `readable/writable/executable` by the relevant user.

In my case I changed my `umask` to `0022`